# Are there any stories, movies or shows that depict a space journey that takes decades but not centuries?

Tags: generation-ship

I know there are sci fi books about generation ships but I'm curious if anyone has ever done a book, movie, or show about what might be considered an intermediate generation ship say for 30 to 50 years trips?

Comment: In a 1928 story ["The Second Swarm"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181761/first-story-to-describe-humans-colonizing-another-planet/181807#181807), people from Earth are exploring the nearer stars (up to 25 light years away) in ships that travel at 2/3 the speed of light.

Answer (score 4):

[Voyage from Yesteryear](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_from_Yesteryear) by James Hogan describes an interstellar voyage that took some two decades rather than centuries.

There were actually several ships described that make the same trip.

There is a lot of detail on the physics of the ships, and realistic descriptions of the workings of the machines and the crew's involvement.

It also has some very speculative ideas about physics, drawn from ideas that were being considered at the time the book was written (late 1970s to early 1980s, published in 1982.)

It also deals with the people and how society evolves, and what an abundance of energy and resources could mean to a society.

It is also about breaking with a lot of common things in all our societies, and a suggestion of what a better society might look like.

A very good story.  Much more interesting than a lot of stuff that gets published.

Comment: It is _very_ poor practice to answer questions that are _clearly_ off-topic. At 3k rep one would expect you to know that.

Comment: Why can't we ask for lists of works in a very specific area of sci fi?