# First named, colonized planet in a science fiction story

Tags: history-of, space-colonization, planets

What is the first non-Sol system planet that's colonized by humans in a work of fiction?

To be specific, I'm not looking for "Proxima Centauri B" or that sort of scientific nomenclature, and no Europa or Ganymede or other Sol-system colonies, but rather the kinds of planet names I vaguely recall from many science fiction stories, but can't remember exactly!

Comment: Not an answer, but where I would start looking for an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_science_fiction

Answer (score 11):

**1900**:  In [*The Struggle for Empire*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1948777), by Robert William Cole, ***Iosia*** is a planet of an unnamed star somewhat more distant than Sirius:

> For a long time past, a band of adventurers had been
> colonizing a planet **called Iosia**, which was situated
> far beyond the confines of the Sirian System.
>
> <sub>*The Struggle for Empire*, Chapter III: The First Note of War</sub>

This planet is first colonized by Earth-humanity but coveted by the people of Kairet (a planet of Sirius) and becomes the flashpoint in the war.

After successfully defeating the Sirians, the Anglo-Saxon Empire (Earth) requires they also cede the planet Maikat:

> The Anglo-Saxons demanded the evacuation of the planet that
> had been the original cause of the war [Iosia], the surrender
> of another planet called Maikat, that belonged to the Sirian
> system, the payment of a huge war indemnity, and the limitation
> of the Sirian war-ships for the future to their own planetary
> system.
>
> <sub>ibid, Chapter XV:  The End of the War</sub>

Answer (score 7):

**1937**: In E.E. "Doc" Smith's "Galactic Patrol", the oldest of his Lensman books, originally serialized in 1937-38, humanity has colonized many planets in the galaxy. Among those named are Valeria, home of Lensman Van Buskirk, and the stormy planet Trenco, source of the valuable substance thionite. Also named is Aldebaran II, though it doesn't live up to your requirement of not being a scientific nomenclature.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**1942:** [Santanni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Foundation_universe_planets#Santanni) and [Trantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trantor) are human-colonized extra-solar planets featured in a number of [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov)'s stories, e.g., in his [*Foundation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series) series. They were introduced in his novelette ["Black Friar of the Flame"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Friar_of_the_Flame), first published in [*Planet Stories*, Spring 1942](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?60022+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v01n10_1942-Sp_sas#page/n3/mode/1up):

> "What good are your rebellions?" came the weary reply. "Are the Lhasinu so
> much more terrible than the oligarchy of Humans that rules Santanni or the dictator that rules Trantor. If the Lhasinu are not Human, they are at least intelligent. Loarism must live at peace with the rulers."

There may well be earlier examples of named human-colonized extra-solar planets in science fiction. Note, however, that the accepted answer to the question [First story to describe humans colonizing another planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181761/first-story-to-describe-humans-colonizing-another-planet) is a 1928 story:

> **1928:** ["The Second Swarm"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55136), a novelette by [Joseph Schlossel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Schlossel), was first published in [*Amazing Stories Quarterly*, Spring 1928](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56167+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_Quarterly_v01n02_1928_Spring/Amazing%20Stories%20Quarterly%20v01n02%201928%20Spring#page/n122/mode/1up), and reprinted in [*Science Fiction Classics*, Summer 1968](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?251442), also available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Science_Fiction_Adventure_Classics_05_1968-Summer#page/n83/mode/1up).

In view of this, it seems unlikely that we will find named extra-solar human colony worlds from before 1928. (The colonized planets in Schlossel's 1928 story are extra-solar, but as far as I can tell without reading it word for word, they are not named.)

Answer (score 2):

### Eosphoros, aka The Morning Star

Sorry to be a party-pooper. Lucian of Samosata explored this in his *True History* in the 2nd Century  AD. The formerly Greek ruler of the Moon starts a war with the ruler of the Sun, intention of putting a colony on the Morning Star (**Eωσφόρος** in the original Greek).

> [Endymion]: "I once assembled all the poor people and needy persons within my dominions, purposing to send a colony to inhabit the Morning Star, because the country was desert and had nobody dwelling in it. This Phaethon envying, crossed me in my design, and sent his Hippomyrmicks to meet with us in the midway, by whom we were surprised at that time, being not prepared for an encounter, and were forced to retire: now therefore my purpose is once again to denounce* [sic] war and publish a plantation of people there".

*The original Greek in Translation 2, *bouloumai authis exenegkein ton polemoi* is "I deliberately intend to go to war", according to Google Translate

Endymion loses the war, but gets to participate in the colony:

> The Heliotans and their colleagues have made a peace with the Selenitans and their associates upon these conditions, that the Heliotans shall cast down the wall, and deliver the prisoners that they have taken upon a ratable ransom: and that the Selenitans should leave the other stars at liberty, and raise no war against the Heliotans, but aid and assist one another if either of them should be invaded: that the king of the Selenitans should yearly pay to the king of the Heliotans in way of tribute ten thousand vessels of dew, and deliver ten thousand of their people to be pledges for their fidelity: that **the colony to be sent to the Morning Star should be jointly supplied by them both, and liberty given to any else that would to be sharers in it**...

OK, I hear you saying: "But this is Sol System!" Is it really? Was there a concept of "Sol System" in the 2nd Century?

Translations

1. Frances Hickes' 1894 translation at Project Gutenberg, https://www.gutenberg.org/files/45858/45858-h/45858-h.htm
2. A. M. Harmon's 1913 translation at Sacred Texts, https://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/luc/true/tru01.htm

The blockquotes are from Translation 1.

Comment: Do you think the Morning Star in Lucian's *True History* qualifies as a "non-Sol system planet" as required by the question?  If so, please address this point in your answer. Or did you just answer the title without reading the question?

Comment: @user14111 Was "Sol System" even a concept in the 2nd Century AD? Do you think Lucian consulted Aristarchus?

Comment: For the purposes of categorizing older stories it would seem natural to interpret "sol system" more broadly as "a system of bodies that includes the sun and the planets we see in the sky and the Earth and moon", without restricting it to heliocentrism.

Comment: The "Morning Star" is Venus, right?